# After update from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2 home page (only) doesn't show the included Static Block in the header

Tags: static-block, header, ce-1.9.2.0

After update from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2, the sites home page doesn't show the included Static Block content in the header area.

All other pages show the Static Block content, its only the home page that is missing the static block content.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe related to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9.2.0 now caches CMS Static Blocks, you may need to refresh the Blocks HTML Output cache or (as there currently appears to be issues with this feature) disable this cache I'm System->Cache Management until a long term fix is issued.

Comment: Did this and it worked! Now I need to keep tabs to find a permanent solution. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this blog,  This helped us in our static block issue. [Magento 1.9.2.0 static block display issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block/73694)