# Magento Category Static block not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I have a running  ecommerce sites built on  magento and in that I have created custom categories for the menu and for each categories I have created static block in the magento's admin panel and linked each one of them to their respective categories.

For ex:-

Category            Linked Static block

1. Faq                 Faq
2. History             History_New
3. Press               Press_New

Now the problem is that when i refresh the cache and click on any category it shows its respective static block data but the same static block data is also displayed for all other categories.

For ex:- If I click on History it shows data from History_New static block but the same data is also displayed when I click on Faq or Press Category.

Visit the site.
http://www.jaydensjuice.com/beta

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Amit and welcome to MageOverflow. Unfortunately this sounds like a problem with a FPC you are using? At least this is no core behavior and therefore not reproduceable for us.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same issue as [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block) one. It's a bug in magento 1.9.2 related to the static block cache

Comment: Yeah the problem seems to be similar but what can the solution for this issue??

Comment: This solution seemed to work. I have displayed Blocks HTML Output cache type from cache management ad the issue seems to be resolved. Anyways thanks for referring me to that issue.

Comment: Add cache key info in Mage_Cms_Block_Block as suggested in the linked answer