# Magento 1.9.2 Redis cache issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, redis, server, ce-1.9.2.0

I have a magento 1.9.2 with Redis cache server.

I have one issue that every time, I make changes, it does not invalidate the cache so to enforce changes I use `redis-cli flushall` every time which is not good because it takes days to recreate cache again.

My question is whether there is any tool that I can install to delete cache keys that are not up to date.

Comment: I have similar issue. After upgrading magento from 1.8.0.0 to 1.9.2.0 redis cache seems to be not validated. I have to manually run 'redis-cli flushall' too. Any solution?

Comment: Seems like it is not Redis Cache issue, but Magento 1.9.2.0 bug. Here is similar discussion http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issues