# Where can I find the specific "performance improvements" for the latest versions of Magento?

Tags: ce-1.9.2.0

I'm running on Magento 1.9.0.1 and looking into what the **Performance** benefits of upgrading to the latest version.

I'm having trouble finding specifics:

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.html

> Other Performance Improvements
>
> • Addressed performance degradation with downloadable products.
>
> • **Numerous performance enhancements.1 and 2**
>
> .....
>
> Acknowledgments
>
> We’d like to thank the following members of the Magento Community for their contributions to this release:
>
> **1 Performance enhancements, Thomas Birke**
>
> **2 Performance enhancements, Ivan Chepurnty**

What specifically are these "performance enhancements" that were included in the latest version?

Comment: CMS static block caching was added...... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you maybe read over it, but it's at the top of your link. i quote:

> Solutions for Developers
>
> Magento Community Edition 1.9.2 includes the latest versions of the
>   Zend 1 Framework and Redis integration, as well as refinements to
>   full-page caching that enable more pages to be served from cache. In
>   addition, this release includes many enhancements as part of our
>   commitment to continually improve product quality and to integrate
>   previous patches into the core code.

Was this what you were looking for or exact code examples?

I have digged some deeper and also saw the following:

> Disabled products no longer appear in the flat catalog table. Resolved
>   an issue that caused the core_cache_tags database table to grow in
>   size.

This would surely enhance database lookup speed and keeps things more organized.