# Static blocks are displayed in the wrong store views when caching is turned on

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, store-view, block-cache

We have a store with multiple store-views, NL, BE & EN.

When we have the "Blocks HTML output" cache activated we have the same footer in every storeview.
So we have a Dutch footer in a English shop or a English footer in our Dutch shop.

However, it’s not only one footer block but all the footer blocks. If we clear the cache its again random which language we get on every storeview. The same issue happens sometimes with slides.
When the Blocks HTML output cache is disabled, everything runs fine. We do not use any other caching extensions and we run Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be applied the patches to your store Magento1.9.1.0, I guess. Anyway there is a ***[troublesome issue with Magento 1.9.2.0 release](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issues)*** and I guess that is what making problem here too..

Problem is recent stable version (ie 1.9.2) included cacheing for static blocks, but it is not enough to uniquely cache each individual static blocks. ***[This is an extension](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache)*** which is specifically use to resolve this issue. (I am the developer of this extension, which is created actually for older versions of magento to caches static blocks effectively.). You can use that.. I have given more details over there.

Comment: Hi, we installed the extension, it fixed the issues of the blocks but we experience performance issues when the module is turned on. The shop started to be really slow. Thereby, there are many many more files created in var/cache.

Comment: okay... I think the random part is making problem here. Okay go to `app/code/community/Rkt/SbCache/Model/Observer.php` and comment the line 58. or remove that line. Let me know whether it helped you or not.  After do the changes, please clear `var/cache` folder