# Magento 1.9 Display Sub Categories On A Category Page

Tags: magento-1.9

My store running on Magento 1.942.

I want to display subcategories on a category page, and find this guide https://www.magemonkeys.com/how-to-display-sub-categories-on-a-category-page-in-magento/.

I create a Static Blocks and subcategory_listing.phtml according to the guide, everything works fine.

but when I enable cache in "Cache Storage Management", All parent categories on my store display the same subcategories (For example, after refreshing the Magento cache, if I click on the A parent category and then click on the other parent category, the subcategories under the A parent category are displayed.).

I refreshed the Magento cache, the browser cache, but nothing changed.

here are the codes of subcategory_listing.phtml

```
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category  = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
->joinUrlRewrite();
?>
<div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing">
<ul id="subcats" class="clear">
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
<?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
<?php Mage::log($_category->debug(), null, 'mylogfile.log'); ?>
<li>
<div class="category-box clearfix">
<a class="now-from-container" href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>"></a>
<div class="category-image-box">
<a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" width="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="category-name">
<h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h2>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"> </div>
```

Comment: Does anyone reply to me?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a solution as well on 1.9.4.2
Looks like an issue similar to what happened in 1.9.2 documented in the link below.
[Blocks HTML Cache & Sub Category Display](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83027/blocks-html-cache-sub-category-display)

I've tried these two modules and neither did the trick.
https://github.com/kirchbergerknorr/Milople_Cms
https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache

Edit: Here is what I ended up doing:

Previously I was trying to add the block as a static block calling the phtml file. 
On this link I got the idea to turn off the cache on the block via xml.
https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/magento-subcategories-category-pages

I ended up using the following method to get subcategories to display correctly and not duplicate for each category:
`<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>`
Which I believe prevents the subcategory block from being cached and duplicating.

My subcategory block was located at ...catalog/navigation/sub_category_listing.phtml

I added my sub categories block to my catalog.xml with:
`<block type="catalog/navigation"  name="sub_category_listing" before="category.products" template="catalog/navigation/sub_category_listing.phtml">
<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
</block>`
And positioned the block with the following in the view.phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/navigation')->setTemplate('catalog/navigation/sub_category_listing.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

I am not going to show the code I used for the subcategory block since I don't know where I got it and there are probably much better examples now (was from an old site I am upgrading). Hope this helps!

Comment: I use your method, and it is working fine on my website, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Thanks

Comment: Clark, can you accept my answer if it worked? Thanks!