# Post 6788 Variables Permissions issue, allowed variable isn't working in block

Tags: security, patches, static-block, supee-6788, directive-whitelist

I've added "design/header/logo_src" to allowed permissions, however in a static block I've made the following call and I'm getting the skin url but not the config path:

```
src="{{skin url="" }}{{config path="design/header/logo_src"}}"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are cached with their own cache id, so you might need to flush the cache after changing permissions.

Speaking of cache, if you are on 1.9.2.0 there is a cache bug with static blocks: [Magento 1.9.2.0 static block display issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issues/73694#73694) It's unlikely, but this might be related your problem if you have a multistore setup where the logo is not configured for every store.

Other than that, the code you show is correct, so it could also just be a misspelling in the variable permissions. Pay attention to leading and trailing whitespace, which is *not* trimmed automatically.