# Magento cache issue (whole website gets messed up)

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, magento-community, static-block

I have problem with my magento website using magento **1.9.2.4.** I have had the cache disabled earlier.

If cache are all switched on, the BuyNow buttons in homepage will not work and cannot add products to shopping cart.

Product details and social sharing info block will disappear on product page.
The problem can be solved by disabling "blocks HTML output" cache.

Then I found that this was  due to Magento Blocks HTML Output cache problem but when  I disable this cache, my site works well.

I followed this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issues)  but not got expected result.

One more problem with cache is when my cache are disable  Interface Locale at admin will not chnage hence some attribute gives error while importing csv.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Review this [link](https://www.milople.com/blogs/magento/solved-magento-static-block-display-issue.html), you can also download script from here.

Comment: I have already tried this but its not working for me.